# Token authentication based on custom user while using django rest_framework

Tags: python, django

I have register page,the users register their data.the thing is I need to provide tokens to registered users while they are registering,for this I have User model,and I added `rest_framework.authtoken` in installed apps and `DEFAULT_PERMSSION` ,`AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`, and I have owner field in User class, when I'm trying to register getting this error `IntegrityError`: `(1048, "Column 'owner_id' cannot be null")` .

views.py

```
def transregister(request):
    if request.POST:
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        # try:

        if request.method == 'POST':

            user = UserForm(request.POST)
            username = request.POST['username']
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            confirm_pwd = request.POST['confirm_pwd']
            company_name = request.POST['company']

            profile_type = request.POST['trainer-company']

            trainerprofile = TrainerForm(request.POST)

            corporate_profile = CorporateProfileForm(request.POST)
            print username


            if user.is_valid():
                userModel = user.save(commit=False)
                userModel.is_user = True
                userModel.is_active=True
                userModel.save()
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    #username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    confirm_pwd = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

  #  User = get_user_model()
    user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    owner = models.ForeignKey('user', related_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    highlighted = models.TextField(default = '')

    objects = UserManager()

    #class Meta:
    #    db_table = u'index_user'


    REQUIRED_FIELDS= ('username',)
    USERNAME_FIELD = ('email')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all())
    #print 'owner'
    #owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','email','company','password','confirm_pwd','is_admin','is_user','is_active','device_id','highlighted','owner')
```

Comment: Which table is it saying that is in? does it give the same error on migration?

Comment: i have inddex_user table,and no error at  migrations time and i have DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASS,DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS   and AUTH_USER_MODEL=index.USER in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py you need to configure the authentication classes to include TokenAuthentication.

To set it in settings.py you should use this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Now since you're also creating your own user model, you need to privide a value for the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting that references your custom model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```